# Bash command to get network information

Tags: bash, networking

I needed a bash command to get current network **bandwidth**, **throughput** and the **network card uptime**, but I haven't found anything that promising online.

I tried getting this kind of information from `/proc/net/dev` but the file doesn't seem to have any manuals about what each value means.

And most network monitoring tools are not `grep`-able or `awk`-able, so they aren't very good for scripts.

Comment: You may want to have a look at [SNMP](http://www.net-snmp.org/) and related graphing tools such as [MRTG](https://oss.oetiker.ch/mrtg/index.en.html), [Cacti](https://www.cacti.net/), etc..

Comment: [bwm-ng](https://github.com/vgropp/bwm-ng) has plain and csv output modes and works well for me in scripts; I'm not sure about network card uptime though

Comment: Bandwidth refers to capacity and unless you are maxing out your capacity you'll never know your bandwidth. Network card uptime will be equivalent to system uptime unless you have something strange going on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi and welcome to stackexchange.

First, what you're looking for isn't a "bash command", you're simply looking for a command line utility.

Second, those kind of metrics have to be collected over time and that consumes resources on your host, so nothing does that by default.

You could create your own metrics by polling the command `ip -s link show <interface>`, for example:

```
$ ip -s link show eth0
2: eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state UP mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
    link/ether b8:ae:ed:72:f3:b3 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    RX:    bytes   packets errors dropped  missed   mcast
    579827124444 443147837      0       0       0 2802393
    TX:    bytes   packets errors dropped carrier collsns
    153295015536 161518564      0       0       0       0
```

Then parse out the `RX:` bytes and `TX:` bytes and store them for later. After a fixed amount of time read those metrics again and calculate your desired values based on the counts and the amount of time passed.

For network card uptime you would probably have to detect the change of state of the network interface, I don't know anything that tracks the time that an interface is brought up.

As noted in the comments, there are third party packages that could do some of this for you, like `bwm-ng`, but it probably isn't installed on your distribution by default. With that said, they will only collect metrics from the time you start the utility.

Comment: I've done what you commented but now I have a doubt, because I've calculated how much Rx and Tx changed overtime in bytes, but throughput should be a single measure, not Received Throughput and Transmitted Throughput

Comment: Then add them together.